# Aperture like event view in Lightroom 5

Tags: lightroom, apple-aperture, file-management

I just purchased Lightroom 5, and am making the switch from Aperture, which I've been using for the last two years, and has all of my 40,000+ images from that time frame.

While I didn't realize that I loved it so much until I couldn't find it, I'm really missing the Event view in LR. Being able to scroll through all of my events and see a visual representation of what was in them instead of simply looking at the text label in the side bar is incredibly useful for me, especially when trying to locate a photo.

Is there a plug in, or a view that I'm simply missing that could in some way emulate this functionality?

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Stack by time : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJn4BoqQPkY

http://lightroomkillertips.com/10-things-aperture-users-need-to-know-about-lightroom/

You can sort by date and then create a smart collection ....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Christian! That almost works, but then I have to view my library's main view like that, right? Does anyone know if Adobe has any plans to implement a view like this? They already have it on the mobile version of lightroom, so they apparently think it's a good idea... ;)